# filter the product collection with an Array in Magento

Tags: php, arrays, magento

I've got this problem that I can't solve. Partly because I can't explain it with the right terms. I'm new to this so sorry for this clumsy question.

Below you can see an overview of my goal.

I'm using Magento CE 1.7.0.2

I have an Array with the name of `$params` in this i have some Category Ids...

```
$_productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')->addAttributeToSelect('*');
```

Here `$_productCollection` is my custom product collection...

How do i filter the product with `addFieldToFilter()` function by category

I tried like `$_productCollection->addFieldToFilter('category',array('eq' => $params));`

But it is not working...

Any ideas...

Comment: This is the first time i'm working with addFieldToFilter()

Comment: Try with `in` instead of `eq`.

Comment: Use inset and explode(',',$params) => ->addFieldToFilter('category',array('inset',explode(',',$params)));

Answer (score 2):

First of all, report product collection  filter not working by catgory.If you have created a new product attribute category then ,it can working

```
$params=array(3,4,812,102);//params always be an array

   $_productCollection= Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addAttributeToFilter('category', array(
'in' => $params,
));
```